# Assign records to an array with the counter

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array

I am assigning records to the array and output it in JSON as an associative array. 
What i am trying to do, along with the result of each record to return the counter, e.g.

`{user_id: "14", fname: "Nicol", lname: "Geo, pass: "1234", counter: "0"}`

`{user_id: "15", fname: "and", lname: "asds", pass: "2145", counter: "1"}`

`{user_id: "17", fname: "asdsds", lname: "gfer", pass: "5", counter: "2"}`

```
<?php

      $json_array = array();

      $mysqli->use_result();

      while ($row = $res->fetch_object()) {
        $counter++; #count record set
        $json_array[] = $row; #assign records to the array
      }

     print_r( json_encode(array('result' => $json_array)) );
```

Comment: Note that you can get the `index` value in jQuery. Since you are returning JSON you may be using something like `$(data.result).each(function(index,data)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try to use `mysqli_fetch_array()` to fetch each row as an associative array and add an item in this array for `"counter"` value:

```
<?php
      // Output
      $json_array = array();

      // Fetch data
      $res = $mysqli->use_result();
      while ($row = $res->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
        $row[] = $counter++;
        $json_array[] = $row; #assign records to the array
      }

      // Echo output
      print_r(json_encode(array('result' => $json_array)) );
?>
```